# pdflatex, xelatex, alternate font style: can I get all that I want?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I'm fairly new to latex, I'm not quite sure of the differences between compilers, and I have to enable a couple of features that are driving me mad. Take this simple document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}

\textOmega\textsuperscript{$-1$} s\textsuperscript{\textit{\textbeta}}

\addfontfeatures{Style=Alternate}{\textit{J-V}}

\end{document}
```

If I compile it with pdflatex, all the greek letters are displayed correctly (with the libertinus font, and italic where needed). However, pdflatex doesn't recognise the command \addfontfeatures{Style=Alternate}{} so it throws an error and doesn't show the alternate style of the letter italic J, see this picture:

[image: pdflatex compile]

If instead I compile with xelatex (or lualatex for what matters) now the \addfontfeatures{Style=Alternate}{} is recognised and applied correctly, but the greek letters are not typeset with the libertinus font anymore, and the beta is not italic anymore, see the picture:

[image: xelatex compile]

Now I ask: is there a way to have both the greek letters and the italic J displayed the way I want?

Comment: don't use textgreek with xelatex/lualatex. Do something like `\newcommand\textOmega{Ω}\newcommand\textbeta{β}` if you want to use commands for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xelatex, you don't need the `textgreek` package, you can just input the letters themselves, but you have to use `fontspec` instead of `libertinus` to get the font. So then the MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} 
\begin{document}
Ω\textsuperscript{$-1$} s\textsuperscript{\textit{β}}

\addfontfeatures{Style=Alternate}{\textit{J-V}}
\end{document}
```

with the output:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I ended up putting the letters directly, and that worked. I didn't call Libertinus that way though, I just used the package.

Comment: Shortest manual ever!  :) Only three sentences: "The package l i b e r t i n u s is only a wrapper for the other two packages libertinus-type1 and libertinus-otf. Depending to the used TEX-engine one of these packages
is loaded. All optional arguments are passed to libertinus-type1 if pdflatex is used or passed to libertinus-otf if xelatex or lualatex are used."